# AngularJS JSON Parsing issue...below is the response i dont know how to parse data

Tags: angularjs, cordova

below is the response

```
{
    "messages": {
        "httpCode": 200,
        "message": "Signed in successfully"
    }
}
```

below is the code for controller, i want to make a loop like if httpCode == 200 and want assign the value to a variable

```
 var res = $http.post('http://webservices.it.com/webservices/services/customerdetail/login', data);
 res.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
     console.log("check", JSON.stringify(data));


     $scope.status = status;

     console.log("data", $scope.data);
     console.log("b1222", $scope.messages);
     console.log("status", $scope.status);
     console.log("status", $scope.headers);
     console.log("status", $scope.config);


     alert(" message: " + JSON.stringify({
         data: data
     }));

 });
 res.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
     $scope.error = data;
     console.log("status", $scope.error);
     alert("failure message: " + JSON.stringify({
         data: data
     }));
 });
 console.log('log', data);
 console.log('Sign-In', $scope.user.username);
 console.log('Sign-In', $scope.user.password);

 $location.path("/Track IMEI");

 }
 };
```

Comment: Please add more context, code to the question.

Comment: the thing is i m done with posting and getting response..i only want to                if (httpCode == 200)
{
// operation 
 }
else{
// operation 
}

Comment: Actually you dont need to parse if it is coming from $http just assign response to a variable.

Comment: how do you assign response to a variable..... i m new in angularjs i m from android background can you please help me

Comment: Can you show us, your call to the backend and the result of this call ?

Comment: please check i have edited the question

Answer (score 0):

```
$http.get("your url")
.success(function(response) {
    $scope.messages = response.messages;
    $scope.httpCode=$scope.messages.httpCode;
    $scope.message=$scope.messages.message;
});
```

In Design:

```
<div>
    <span><h2>{{httpCode}}</h2></span><br>
    <span><h2>{{message}}</h2></span><br>
</div>
```